# AgentWork trigger is not firing before or after insert events

Tags: trigger, before-trigger, after-trigger

I have created an after/before insert trigger defined on AgentWork object. When a case is created from Email to Case, the record is automatically routed to an available Agent from a queue by Omni-Channel routing.

**Here is my code:**

```
trigger AgentWorkTrigger on AgentWork (before insert, before update, after insert, after update) {
    Map<Id, Case> casesToUpdate = new Map<Id, Case>();
    String workItemId = null;

    for (AgentWork newAgentWork : trigger.new) {
        workItemId = String.valueOf(newAgentWork.WorkItemId);
        if (workItemId != null && workItemId.substring(0, 3) == Case.sObjectType.getDescribe().getKeyPrefix()) {
            casesToUpdate.put(workItemId, new Case(Id = workItemId, AssignDateTime__c = newAgentWork.AssignedDateTime));
        }
    }
    if (casesToUpdate.size() > 0) {
        update casesToUpdate.values();
    }
}
```

The problem is that this trigger is not firing on insert, but the case record is accepted via Omni-Channel and the update event fires.

**for you info:**
Trigger is active. I managed to debug the trigger. As I expected, trigger does not fire at all at insert event. If I updateCase the Update event fires, and I am able to view its debug log.
**I don't see anything reasonable on why this trigger would not fire at AgentWork record creation.**

Comment: Interestingly, I found an older unanswered question asking the exact same thing: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/117817/agentwork-before-after-insert-trigger-is-not-executing.

The SFDC docs state "Some operations don’t invoke triggers.
Triggers are invoked for data manipulation language (DML) operations that are initiated or processed by the Java application server. Therefore, some system bulk operations don't invoke triggers". https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_ignoring_operations.htm

AgentWork isn't included or excluded

Comment: As I haven't found anything related Operations That Don't Invoke AgentWork Trigger Events